# Fluent Nhibernate issue with the join table when creating a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, join

I am using Fluent Nhibernate. I have two objects linked with a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class Order()
{
    public virtual IList Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product()
{
    public virtual IList Orders { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings are the following:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    HasManyToMany<Product>(x => x.Products).Table("OrderProduct").ParentKeyColumn("ProductId").ChildKeyColumn("OrderId").Cascade.All();
}

public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    HasManyToMany<Order>(x => x.Orders).Table("OrderProduct").ParentKeyColumn("OrderId").ChildKeyColumn("ProductId").Inverse().Cascade.All();
}
```

The join table (OrderProduct) is created but it has only two fields: ProductId and OrderId. It has no primary key.

What I would like is the join table to have three fields: a primary key (say OrderProductId) and the two fields (ProductId and OrderId) and the tables Order and Products to have a foreign key referencing the primary key of the join table (OrderProductId). Is that possible? And how?

Thanks.